# Is there a shortcut in Xcode for partial codeSense confirmation?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

By partial codeSense confirmation I mean a situation like this:

1) I want to declare a type `NSLayoutConstraint`, but I want to be helped by codeSense while typing it to save keystrokes as it's complete waste of time.

2) After I type `NSLay`, codeSense, because of its history cache, is giving me as first option `NSLayoutFormatOptions`.

[image]

3) To narrow the suggestions to this

[image]

I have to **type** "o", "u", "t" and C characters **explicitly**.

---

> Is there a shortcut that would allow me to confirm the "o", "u", "t" characters ..basically confirm everything to the next **CAP**italized character , and then just type C to get the constraint class? (which is really the most common so Xcode might really be a bit smarter about this :(  )

Comment: press `Tab`, it does the job.

Comment: you deserve reputation.,,pls make it proper answer.

Comment: someone else needs more reputation than me. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>⇥</kbd> (tab) will accept the longest substring that is a match in *all* suggestions (i.e. up until the first character that is different in any of the suggestions).

Pressing <kbd>↩︎</kbd> (enter) will accept the full suggestion.

---

For example, typing "NSLa" with these suggestions (in image below). Pressing <kbd>⇥</kbd> (tab) here will complete until "NSLayout" (because NSLayoutConstraint and NSLayoutFormat... is still in the list of suggestions) and pressing <kbd>↩︎</kbd> (enter) will complete "NSLayoutAttribute"

[image]